# Does OpenSSH really replaces the programs that it says it does?

Tags: windows, openssh

In www.openssh.org I read the following lines:

`The OpenSSH suite replaces rlogin and telnet with the ssh program, rcp with scp, and ftp with sftp. Also included is sshd (the server side of the package), and the other utilities like ssh-add, ssh-agent, ssh-keysign, ssh-keyscan, ssh-keygen and sftp-server.`

Does that really mean that it replaces all these stuff and it will break stuff on the server?
Or does it mean that it offers these alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That manual page was written at least a decade ago (those programs were replaced long before that). Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mean that it offers these alternatives. By default, ssh use de port 22 and telnet the port 23. So if you use scp it will connect to the remote ssh server. If you use rcp it will connect to the telnet server and everything will be separate and work independently.

Comment: So installing it wont affect any of the other stuff that we're using so far. Right?

Comment: @DeusDeceit: Right (assuming a sane installation program). Certainly on Linux installing OpenSSH doesn't clobber those other commands; I'd be very surprised if it did so on Windows. Note that the commands have different names, so there's no reason to remove the older ones.